# How to extract substring between two strings, INCLUDING the matching/enclosing strings?

Tags: xml, sed

I have an XML file and I need to extract an element from the XML file (on Linux machine), but unfortunately, the machine doesn't have the "xsltproc" command (and I cannot get it installed), so I am trying to figure how to do the extract using other tools that are available (e.g., sed, etc.).

Here's an example of the XML:

```
<l7:List xmlns:l7="http://ns.l7tech.com/2010/04/gateway-management">
    <l7:Name>REVOCATION_CHECK_POLICY List</l7:Name>
    <l7:Type>List</l7:Type>
    <l7:TimeStamp>2022-05-30T12:36:16.994Z</l7:TimeStamp>
    <l7:Link rel="self" uri="https://myhost02.xxxx.com:8443/restman/1.0/revocationCheckingPolicies"/>
    <l7:Link rel="template" uri="https://myhost02.xxxx.com:8443/restman/1.0/revocationCheckingPolicies/template"/>
    <l7:Item>
        <l7:Name>OCSPREVOCATIONVALIDATION</l7:Name>
        <l7:Id>a60c5a8714b2e519a6c23192cf09ded5</l7:Id>
        <l7:Type>REVOCATION_CHECK_POLICY</l7:Type>
        <l7:TimeStamp>2022-05-30T12:36:16.994Z</l7:TimeStamp>
        <l7:Link rel="self" uri="https://myhost02.xxxx.com:8443/restman/1.0/revocationCheckingPolicies/a60c5a8714b2e519a6c23192cf09ded5"/>
        <l7:Resource>
            <l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy id="a60c5a8714b2e519a6c23192cf09ded5" version="20">
                <l7:Name>OCSPREVOCATIONVALIDATION</l7:Name>
                <l7:DefaultPolicy>true</l7:DefaultPolicy>
                <l7:ContinueOnServerUnavailable>false</l7:ContinueOnServerUnavailable>
                <l7:DefaultSuccess>false</l7:DefaultSuccess>
                <l7:RevocationCheckItems>
                    <l7:Type>OCSP from URL</l7:Type>
                    <l7:Url>http://foo.west.dev.xxxx.com:80</l7:Url>
                    <l7:AllowIssuerSignature>true</l7:AllowIssuerSignature>
                    <l7:TrustedSigners>3c880ed5addceb2e9ef308074f2c353f</l7:TrustedSigners>
                </l7:RevocationCheckItems>
            </l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy>
        </l7:Resource>
    </l7:Item>
</l7:List>
```

I need to extract the following XML into a separate variable or file:

```
            <l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy id="a60c5a8714b2e519a6c23192cf09ded5" version="20">
                <l7:Name>OCSPREVOCATIONVALIDATION</l7:Name>
                <l7:DefaultPolicy>true</l7:DefaultPolicy>
                <l7:ContinueOnServerUnavailable>false</l7:ContinueOnServerUnavailable>
                <l7:DefaultSuccess>false</l7:DefaultSuccess>
                <l7:RevocationCheckItems>
                    <l7:Type>OCSP from URL</l7:Type>
                    <l7:Url>http://foo.west.dev.xxxx.com:80</l7:Url>
                    <l7:AllowIssuerSignature>true</l7:AllowIssuerSignature>
                    <l7:TrustedSigners>3c880ed5addceb2e9ef308074f2c353f</l7:TrustedSigners>
                </l7:RevocationCheckItems>
            </l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy>
```

I am able to "flatten" the file into a single string using:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' response.xml
```

but then I have to try to extract the string that I need (between the:

```
<l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy
```

and the:

```
</l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy>
```

INCLUSIVE of the two matching strings.

I can extract the subtring WITHOUT the matching strings:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' response.xml | sed -e 's/.*<l7\:RevocationCheckingPolicy\(.*\)<\/l7\:RevocationCheckingPolicy>.*/\1/'
```

which gives me:

```
 id="a60c5a8714b2e519a6c23192cf09ded5" version="20">                            <l7:Name>OCSPREVOCATIONVALIDATION</l7:Name>                    <l7:DefaultPolicy>true</l7:DefaultPolicy>                    <l7:ContinueOnServerUnavailable>false</l7:ContinueOnServerUnavailable>                    <l7:DefaultSuccess>false</l7:DefaultSuccess>                    <l7:RevocationCheckItems>                        <l7:Type>OCSP from URL</l7:Type>                        <l7:Url>http://foo.west.dev.xxxx.com:80</l7:Url>                        <l7:AllowIssuerSignature>true</l7:AllowIssuerSignature>                        <l7:TrustedSigners>3c880ed5addceb2e9ef308074f2c353f</l7:TrustedSigners>                    </l7:RevocationCheckItems>
```

But that XML is missing the enclosing strings:

```
<l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy
```

at the beginning and the:

```
</l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy>
```

I've seen some suggestion of just including the enclosing strings in front of, and after, the:

```
.*
```

in the 2nd sed, but when I tried that, it seems like that is causing the 2nd sed to not even match at all.

Can someone tell me how to include the enclosing strings?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, get the required element with a xml tool as `xmllint`.
**Advantages**: works regardless of namespace prefix and XML file format.

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="RevocationCheckingPolicy"]' test.xml
```

Result

```
<l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy id="a60c5a8714b2e519a6c23192cf09ded5" version="20">
        <l7:Name>OCSPREVOCATIONVALIDATION</l7:Name>
        <l7:DefaultPolicy>true</l7:DefaultPolicy>
        <l7:ContinueOnServerUnavailable>false</l7:ContinueOnServerUnavailable>
        <l7:DefaultSuccess>false</l7:DefaultSuccess>
        <l7:RevocationCheckItems>
          <l7:Type>OCSP from URL</l7:Type>
          <l7:Url>http://foo.west.dev.xxxx.com:80</l7:Url>
          <l7:AllowIssuerSignature>true</l7:AllowIssuerSignature>
          <l7:TrustedSigners>3c880ed5addceb2e9ef308074f2c353f</l7:TrustedSigners>
        </l7:RevocationCheckItems>
      </l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy>
```

Alternatively, it can be done using `--shell` option as

```
echo 'cat //*[local-name()="RevocationCheckingPolicy"]' | xmllint --shell test.xml
```

Comment: Hi  @LMC - I forgot to mention that I *HAD* tried xmllint after I found that machine doesn't have xsltproc, but the version of xmllint on that machine didn't support the --xpath parameter.  My mistake for not mentioning, and I did test what you suggested on a different machine with an xmllint that does support --xpath and it was good, so while your response wasn't applicable to my situation (cuz I cannot upgrade the xmllint either), it was my omission, so I marked your post above also as Answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @user555303 updated the answer with an alternative way of doing this with `xmllint`, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/<l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy/,\|</l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy>|p' input_file > outfile
$ cat outfile
            <l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy id=a60c5a8714b2e519a6c23192cf09ded5 version=20>
                <l7:Name>OCSPREVOCATIONVALIDATION</l7:Name>
                <l7:DefaultPolicy>true</l7:DefaultPolicy>
                <l7:ContinueOnServerUnavailable>false</l7:ContinueOnServerUnavailable>
                <l7:DefaultSuccess>false</l7:DefaultSuccess>
                <l7:RevocationCheckItems>
                    <l7:Type>OCSP from URL</l7:Type>
                    <l7:Url>http://foo.west.dev.xxxx.com:80</l7:Url>
                    <l7:AllowIssuerSignature>true</l7:AllowIssuerSignature>
                    <l7:TrustedSigners>3c880ed5addceb2e9ef308074f2c353f</l7:TrustedSigners>
                </l7:RevocationCheckItems>
            </l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy>
```

Comment: WOW!  That is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting `awk` script:

```
awk '/<l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy /,/l7:RevocationCheckingPolicy>/' input.xml
```